# Connecting SQL task to data flow task programatically (c#)

Tags: c#, ssis

How can I connect a SQL task to a data flow task programatically?

SQL Task:

```
Executable exec = package.Executables.Add("STOCK:SQLTask");
TaskHost thMainPipe = (TaskHost)exec;
```

...

Data flow:

```
MainPipe mp = ((TaskHost)stagingPackage.Executables.Add("DTS.Pipeline")).InnerObject as MainPipe;
```

...

Tried using PrecedenceConstraints.Add, get COM error.

```
PrecedenceConstraints.Add(derivedTask,(Executable) mp);
```

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Executable'.

Comment: Use STOCK:PipelineTask in place of DTS.Pipeline

Comment: post complete code block to understand this issue, thnx

Comment: S.M, it worked. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: See my post as an answer, Up Vote / Accept my answer if it's solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use STOCK:PipelineTask in place of DTS.Pipeline. Executables.Add() Method expect CLSID, PROGID, STOCK moniker, or CreationName property of the TaskInfo object. STOCK moniker is mostly used. DTS.Pipeline might not have recognized as any of them. If not using Stock Moniker, specify CLSID or PROGID equivalent to STOCK:PipelineTask.